# How to validate that a method annotation is using an attribute with an specific value using archunit

Tags: java, junit, archunit

I have an `@Audit` annotation, it has many optional attributes, I need to enforce the use of one boolean attribute `useAccount = true` for certain packages.

I am trying to use archunit to accomplish this validation, that way whenever a developer commits code that breaks the rule the CI will break and inform the team.

This would break the build:

```
@Audit
public myMethod(...) {
...
}
```

This is the right way:

```
@Audit(useAccount = true)
public myMethod(...) {
...
}
```

The problem is that Archunit doesn't currently support asserting over methods. I was expecting to do something like:

```
methods().that().resideInAnyPackage("..controllers..", "..service..").and().areAnnotatedWith(Audit.class).should(attributeCheckCondition)
```

Then my custom condition `attributeCheckCondition` would take care of looking into the attribute value.

Is there a way of retrieving methods as we retrieve classes? Without having to write a more complicated predicate and condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Since ArchUnit 0.10.0 it is possible to create rules for members.

```
methods().that()
  .areDeclaredInClassesThat()
  .resideInAnyPackage("..controllers..", "..service..")
  .and()
  .areAnnotatedWith(Audit.class)
  .should(attributeCheckCondition)
```

See also [Composing Member Rules](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_composing_member_rules) in the User Guide.

### Original Answer

Since there are currently no basic rule definitions available for methods, an intermediate step is necessary. ArchUnit has a `ClassesTransformer` to transform JavaClasses into a collection of other types.

```
ClassesTransformer<JavaMethod> methods = new AbstractClassesTransformer<JavaMethod>("methods") {
    @Override
    public Iterable<JavaMethod> doTransform(JavaClasses javaClasses) {
        Set<JavaMethod> allMethods = new HashSet<>();
        for (JavaClass javaClass : javaClasses) {
            allMethods.addAll(javaClass.getMethods());
        }
        return allMethods;
    }
};
```

This `ClassesTransformer` can then be used as a base for custom rule definitions.

```
ArchRule rule = ArchRuleDefinition.all(methods)
    .that(owner(resideInAnyPackage("..controllers..", "..service..")))
    .and(annotatedWith(Audit.class))
    .should(haveAttributeValue());
rule.check(javaClasses);
```

See also [Rules with Custom Concepts](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_rules_with_custom_concepts) in the User Guide and [this issue](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/38).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way of doing it with custom predicate and condition over classes, when I did that I was not aware of Roland's response which seems to be better, as it provides a way to express the rule assertion from the methods perspective which is why I was asking for.

However I wanted to post the solution here so it can be useful for others.

```
DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> HAVE_A_METHOD_ANNOTATED_WITH_AUDIT =
    new DescribedPredicate<JavaClass>("have a method annotated with @Audit")
    {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(JavaClass input)
        {
            return input.getMethods().stream().anyMatch(method -> method.isAnnotatedWith(Audit.class));
        }
    };

ArchCondition<JavaClass> ONLY_SET_ATTRIBUTE_USE_ACCOUNT_SET_TO_TRUE =
    new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("only set useAccount attribute to true")
    {
        @Override
        public void check(JavaClass item, ConditionEvents events)
        {
            item.getMethods().stream().filter(method ->
           method.isAnnotatedWith(Audit.class) && !method.getAnnotationOfType(Audit.class)
                                                            .useAccount()
            )
                .forEach(method -> {
                    String message = String.format(
                        "Method %s is annotated with @Audit but useAccount is not set to true",
                        method.getFullName());
                    events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(method, message));
                });
        }
    };
```

Then the rule is expressed as:

```
ArchRule ANNOTATION_RULE = classes()
    .that()
    .resideInAnyPackage("..controller..", "..service..")
    .and(HAVE_A_METHOD_ANNOTATED_WITH_AUDIT)
    .should(ONLY_SET_ATTRIBUTE_USE_ACCOUNT_SET_TO_TRUE);
```

Comment: Fun fact: I had a similar problem the day before you asked the question and I solved it the same way you did. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is another custom example in addition to @raspacorp (who inspired me!).

To check `@Secured(ROLE)` method annotation, I've implemented the following rule:

```
public static class SecuredByRoleArchCondition extends ArchCondition<JavaMethod> {
    private final String[] expectedRoles;

    public SecuredByRoleArchCondition(String[] expectedRoles) {
        super(String.format("accessed by @Secured methods with roles %s", Arrays.toString(expectedRoles)));
        this.expectedRoles = expectedRoles;
    }

    public static SecuredByRoleArchCondition haveSecuredAnnotationWithRoles(String... expectedRoles) {
        return new SecuredByRoleArchCondition(expectedRoles);
    }

    @Override
    public void check(JavaMethod javaMethod, ConditionEvents events) {
        if (!javaMethod.isAnnotatedWith(Secured.class)) {
            String message = String.format("Method %s annotation @Secured(%s) is missing",
                    javaMethod.getFullName(), Arrays.toString(expectedRoles));
            events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(javaMethod, message));
            return;
        }
        String[] annotationRoleValues = javaMethod.getAnnotationOfType(Secured.class).value();
        if (!Arrays.equals(annotationRoleValues, expectedRoles)) {
            String message = String.format("Method %s @Secured with %s has wrong roles, expected %s instead",
                    javaMethod.getFullName(), Arrays.toString(annotationRoleValues), Arrays.toString(expectedRoles));
            events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(javaMethod, message));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample usage of this archCondition:

```
@ArchTest
static ArchRule admin_actions_with_post_mapping_should_be_secured_by_ADMIN_WRITE_role =
        methods()
                .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().resideInAnyPackage(ADMIN_PACKAGES)
                .and().areAnnotatedWith(PostMapping.class)
                .should(haveSecuredAnnotationWithRoles("ADMIN_WRITE"));
```